# Reading blocks of data from multiple CSV files and combining them into a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse

I have multiple CSV files that I can read into dataframes. Each resultant dataframe consists of blocks of rows stacked on top of each other and separated by a row of NA's. blocks of each file have the same number of rows (and obviously the same number of columns.) For example, the first dataframe has the following structure:

B1

B2

...

Bn

where Bi is the ith block with p rows, for each i, and blocks are separated by a row of NA's. I don't necessarily know the number of blocks (i.e. n), albeit figuring it out is easy math.

I need to combine all these dataframes into one, by

- reading the first block from the 1st df, then reading the first block from the 2nd df, ..., till reading the first block from the last df.
- then reading the second block from the dfs sequentially, ...
- doing this till all the blocks are stacked on top of each other in one final dataframe.

To make it more clear, assume there are only 2 dfs, where the first one is structured as described above, and the second one has the following structure:

A1

A2

...

An

where each block Aj has q rows and  blocks are separated by an NA row (note that p and q are not necessarily the same, but both dfs have the same number of columns.)

The final df should have the following structure:

B1

A1

B2

A2

...

Bn

An

Is there an elegant way of doing this in R without resorting to for-loops?

Comment: It would really help to see structure a bit less vague than "B1 could be any number of rows". Can you provide some details? For instance, if there's one column that indicates to which block a row belongs it would help immensely.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, sure. In my example, each block B is a matrix of of p rows and c columns, and each block A is a matrix of q rows and c columns. p, q, and c are known numbers.